# Как создать поддомен?

Tags: домен, веб-программирование

Мне нужно сделать поддомен на своём сайте, например, http://v1-1.on-road.su/, вопрос вот какой: как создать этот поддомен и выложить в него содержание страницы? И ещё один. Наверное, все видели сейчас рекламу в интернете: "Конструктор сайтов", там тоже самое, только создают сайты, а перед этим выбирают поддомен, но как выкладывают эти сайты на сервер с поддоменным адресом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Физически поддомен представляет собой обычную директорию на сервере, но программное обеспечение сервера обрабатывает его "по-особеному". Т.е. мы получим одинаковый результат перейдя по http://**v1-1**.on-road.su и по ссылке http://on-road.su**/v1-1**. Поддомен можно создать в контрольной панели управления сайтом.

Comment: Спасибо, а как создаются сайты с поддоменами в конструкторах?

Comment: В каких именно конструкторах? Те, которые предлагают пошаговое создание сайта? Не уверен, что в них есть такие возможности. Легче взять обычный хостинг - возможностей больше и удобнее

Comment: Просто интересно, я думаю создан файл "робот" который автоматически создаёт поддомен и вставляет туда содержимое сайта. Думаю вопрос исчерпан